# Can human input determine steps in BPMN?

Tags: business-process-management

I have a process

1. Receive Message
2. Run rules against message (Output: Verify|Do Not verify)
3. If Do Not Verify Then no further action required.
4. If verify Then ask user to check the message (put it on user queue)
5. User inspects message and may also decide to run additional checks against the message.
6. Based on output of those additional checks, user can approve or decline the message
7. Done.

My question is on step #5 can the user be presented with a checkbox list of additional "processes" they would like to execute against this message and the BPM call only those steps that where picked.

So the user is presented with a list of check boxes (A, B, C) and they would like to execute A and C. Can the BPM only then execute A and C and continue?

Answer (score 1):

Usually you would model such a behavior by having an or gateway placed on the diagram. Depending what the value of the variable containing the user choices, one or more paths may be chosen. You can also set a default path.

I hope this helps.